# prevent browser to play mp3 in new browser window

Tags: html, browser, mp3

is there a way to prevent a browser from opening an mp3 in a new browser window?

i have a normal link to mp3 file like

```
 <a href="link_to_mp3">some.mp3</a>
```

and of course you can download it with right click -> save as. but some users don't know that. so if they click on a link, a new window opens where they can listen to that mp3.

issue is, i want the users to download the files once instead of listen to them thousand times over my server ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through html only you cannot force the link to open a file save dialog.

Instead you can achieve that through `PHP` and with some custom headers [as seen here](http://www.ryboe.com/tutorials/php-headers-force-download)

A simple download.php file could look like:

```
    <?php
     
     $file = $_GET['file'];
     $dir = "path/to/files/";
     
     if(!file)
     {
         die('file not found');
     }
     else
     {
         $local_file = $dir . $file['filename'];
         $file = fopen($local_file, "r");  


         header("Cache-Control: public");
         header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
         header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
         header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
         header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        
         // set download rate
         $download_rate = 100.0;
         // fetch the file
         fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024)); 
         // close the file stream
         fclose($file);
     }
     ?>
```

Where you can specify the directory where all your files as saved, as well as a download rate if needed to limit the speed at which the file can be downloaded.

### Update

Forgot to mention that you will then change your links to:

```
 <a href="download.php?file=test.mp3">some.mp3</a>
```

where test.mp3 will be changed to your particular download

Answer (score 1):

quick and dirty: maybe you .zip it...than the browser automatically downloads the file

Comment: yeah, one way...but i m not sure if users who don t now the right-click move are more used to zip files ;)

Comment: @longilong good point...probably they don't ;-) to be sure you could write a supersize blinky message to right click...but i'm sure there are still many people dont now to manage that ;-P Sorry i cannot help you any further...

Comment: hehe..well, i thought about the same, but didn't had the idea of a blinky one :D 

and now there s the thing with the look and feel of the page, which will be ruined in both cases.. i m quite sure there s a way to handle this, still i didn t found sth in the web yet

Comment: `PHP` as my answer is not an option? With html alone i dont think there's a way to force the browser especially considering the download managers and addons that one may have installed...

Comment: @Jurudocs It isn't (imo), as long as there is no good reason to not use PHP, then this or a similar option would be best suited in this case

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your script. it didn t worked out for me, because the $local_file variable wasn't build right.. don t ask, not really a php pro. still your post put me in the right direction. here s my solution

```
<?php
$downloadfile = "directory/".$_GET['file'];
$filename = $_GET['file'];
$filesize = filesize($downloadfile);

header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg3"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 
header("Content-Length: $filesize");

readfile($downloadfile);
exit;
?>
```

oh, and for other php-dummies: NO WHITESPACE AT THE BEGINNING OF THE SCRIPT!!!